# Ionic/Cordova App: How to change to another template in button click?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing and app in Ionic and I need that after you click in button it takes you to another template. This template is called **area.html** and is not in the sidemenu, I added as a *state* of it in **app.js** . Here you have some code:

**app.js**

```
.state('app.area', {
    url: "/area",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/area.html",
        controller: 'AreaCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

**firsttemplate.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="First Template">
  <ion-content class="background">

    <button class="button button-positive"
            ng-click="changeToArea()">Current Position</button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('FirstTempCtrl', function ($scope){

      $scope.changeToArea = function() {
      console.log("Area Func");
      window.location = "#/app/area.html";
    })
```

The thing is that when you click in the button it take you to another template, to the :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/log');
```

in the **app.js** and what I want to load is **area.html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 window.location = "#/app/area.html";
```

will reload your app and therefore all controllers

you need to use ui-router  with for exemple : `$state.go('app.area');`

Comment: This worked perfectly, I tried before but it wasn't working well but now it is. Thank you